# SQL - GROUPBY query

Tags: sql, group-by

I have data that looks like this. There are different buckets, that have multiple IDs, and some of those IDs have data and some don't. For e.g. A6, L1 and L2 are all in the same bucket (Bucket1), and A6 has data but L1 and L2 don't.

[image]

I'm trying to write a query that sums the distinct number of IDs in a bucket that have data (TRUE volume), and also sum the count of IDs that don't have data (FALSE volume), and then it adds the 2 volumes to create total volume. You can see the addition below:

[image]

This is what I have till now:

```
select 
Buckets, 
case 
    when Date is not null then count(distinct Data)
    end as TRUE_Vol,
case 
    when Date is null then 0 
    end as FALSE_Vol

from #temptable
group by Buckets, Date, Data
```

But this code is not giving me what I want. I think I need to group it differently, but I can't figure that out. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a selective group by

```
select 
Buckets, 
sum ( case  when Date is not null then 1 else 0 end) as TRUE_Vol,
sum ( case  when Date is null then 1 else 0 end) as FALSE_Vol

from #temptable
group by Buckets
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a follow up question. When I use this query, it gives me an output of '3' of 'bucket1' - it counts the total number of times the data appears in that bucket for that ID. I'm looking for output as '1'. Is there any way that I can sum(distinct ID)? I tried, but it wouldn't let me do it because ID is a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use conditional aggregation, the `case` goes inside the aggregation function.

Based on your description, you want:

```
select Buckets, 
       count(distinct case when Date is not null then Data end) as TRUE_Vol,
       sum(case when Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as FALSE_Vol
from #temptable
group by Buckets;
```